# linking to a custom library using cmake

Tags: c++, linker, cmake

I have two cmake files that build a directory and then try to compile an example that uses that library.  The content of the first CMakeLists.txt file stored at the project root `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project("lsd_point_pair")

SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH  ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

#Note: Eclipse automatically picks up include paths with this on!
SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)


SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g")


find_package(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

set(BOOST_LIBS program_options)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS ${BOOST_LIBS} REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
MESSAGE("  Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")

include_directories(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
link_directories(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib})  


add_library(lsd_obj_rec_ransac lsd_obj_rec_ransac.cpp lsd_obj_rec_ransac.h lsd_point_pair_model_library.cpp lsd_point_pair_model_library.h ndim_voxel_structure.h orr_octree_cloud.h orr_octree_cloud.cpp)
target_link_libraries(lsd_obj_rec_ransac ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})   

######## subdirectories #########
add_subdirectory(examples)
```

In `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}`/examples I have the following CMakeLists.txt file:

```
add_executable(example_pcl_lsd_point_pair example_pcl_lsd_point_pair.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example_pcl_lsd_point_pair lsd_obj_rec_ransac ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

After successfully running cmake I run make and I get the linking errors:

```
CMakeFiles/example_pcl_lsd_point_pair.dir/example_pcl_lsd_point_pair.cpp.o: In function `~LSDObjRecRANSAC':
make[2]: Leaving directory `/media/Data/Documents/Grad/research/Projects/LSDPointPairs/qtcreator-build'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/media/Data/Documents/Grad/research/Projects/LSDPointPairs/qtcreator-build'
/home/mustafa/projects/LSDPointPairs/examples/../lsd_obj_rec_ransac.h:44: undefined reference to `pcl::recognition::ORROctreeCloud::~ORROctreeCloud()'
/home/mustafa/projects/LSDPointPairs/examples/../lsd_obj_rec_ransac.h:44: undefined reference to `pcl::recognition::ORROctreeCloud::~ORROctreeCloud()'
../lib/liblsd_obj_rec_ransac.a(lsd_obj_rec_ransac.cpp.o): In function `LSDObjRecRANSAC':
/home/mustafa/projects/LSDPointPairs/lsd_obj_rec_ransac.cpp:18: undefined reference to `pcl::recognition::LSDPointPairModelLibrary::LSDPointPairModelLibrary(float, float, float)'
/home/mustafa/projects/LSDPointPairs/lsd_obj_rec_ransac.cpp:18: undefined reference to `pcl::recognition::ORROctreeCloud::ORROctreeCloud()'
/home/mustafa/projects/LSDPointPairs/lsd_obj_rec_ransac.cpp:18: undefined reference to `pcl::recognition::ORROctreeCloud::~ORROctreeCloud()'
../lib/liblsd_obj_rec_ransac.a(lsd_point_pair_model_library.cpp.o): In function `LSDPointPairModel':
/home/mustafa/projects/LSDPointPairs/lsd_point_pair_model_library.h:36: undefined reference to `pcl::recognition::ORROctreeCloud::ORROctreeCloud()'
/home/mustafa/projects/LSDPointPairs/lsd_point_pair_model_library.h:36: undefined reference to `pcl::recognition::ORROctreeCloud::~ORROctreeCloud()'
../lib/liblsd_obj_rec_ransac.a(lsd_point_pair_model_library.cpp.o): In function `~LSDPointPairModel':
/home/mustafa/projects/LSDPointPairs/lsd_point_pair_model_library.h:27: undefined reference to `pcl::recognition::ORROctreeCloud::~ORROctreeCloud()'
/home/mustafa/projects/LSDPointPairs/lsd_point_pair_model_library.h:27: undefined reference to `pcl::recognition::ORROctreeCloud::~ORROctreeCloud()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/example_pcl_lsd_point_pair] Error 1
make[1]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/example_pcl_lsd_point_pair.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The library **successfully gets built** because I see the liblsd_obj_rec_ransac.a file gets generated.  But the problem happens when trying to compile the example.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried typing `make VERBOSE=1` to check that the paths for all of your required libraries are correct?

Comment: Alternatively, insert a `message(${PCL_LIBRARIES})` before your `target_link_libraries(...)` line. Chances are that you are simply passing an empty string here instead of the actual library name.

Comment: Actually linking to PCL is fine.  All the header files mentioned in the error are from my custom built library.  The header files for the custom library are also under the name space PCL.  I am doing this because I am looking to contribute these files to the PCL library in the future.

Comment: Also the linking errors are happening between files within the custom library.  What is confusing is that when I simply build the library on it own it builds successfully but when I try to compile an example file which uses this library the linking errors in the library appear.  Shouldn't have those linking errors appeared when I initially compiled the library on it own??

Comment: Problem Solved.  It was because OrrOctreeCloud class in the custom library had a declared default constructor/destructor that was never defined in the .cpp file.  This prevented the constructor from generating the default constructor and destructor for that class.